# Youtube embedded video - remove final info screen

Tags: video, youtube, embed

Is there a way I can remove the final screen of an embedded YouTube video, that has the "replay" button, listing other videos, URL and Embed options etc?

I just want the video to end, and not see anything else?

Thanks

EDIT: Solved it!! rel=0 in the video URL!

I have the following params in my video URL, that made the title go, and the end info window go:

showsearch=0&showinfo=0&playlist=&modestbranding=1&egm=0&rel=0

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question by the way...I would check to make sure it's not a duplicate first though.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have this video:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/GeyDf4ooPdo
```

you need to add the [option rel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel) (`?rel=0`) to the end, as a parameter.

Like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/GeyDf4ooPdo?rel=0
```

Here you can find some parameters: [Youtube Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters), and some tricks: [Tricks](http://www.techairlines.com/useful-youtube-url-tricks/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&rel=0` parameter to disable related videos at the end. For quick,easy and more customizations of youtube embed player try using [Advanced Youtube Embed Code Generator](http://codegena.com/generator/Youtube-Embed-Code-Generator.html)